# Vue 3 TypeScript Class Component props don't work properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, class

Whenever I define that my custom component has props, I get the following error in build:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _components_Menu_vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__.default is not a constructor`

I'm basically building a Menu with SubMenu capability, and running into an issue when trying to define a SubMenu as the root, in which case, it should show a label as a "header" instead of a button.

Here's the code for the SubMenu:

```
<template>
    <ul v-if="items">
      <template v-for="(item, i) of items">

        <li v-if="visible(item) && !item.separator">
          <template v-if="!!root">
            <div>
              {{ item.label }}
            </div>
            <SubMenu v-if="visible(item)"
                     :items="item.items" />
          </template>
          <template v-else>
            <router-link v-if="item.to"
                         :to="item.to"
                         :target="item.target">
              <i :class="item.icon" />
              <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
              <i v-if="item.items" class="down-arrow" />
            </router-link>

            <a v-if="!item.to" :href="item.url || '#'"
               :target="item.target">
              <i :class="item.icon" />
              <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
              <i v-if="item.items" class="down-arrow" />
            </a>
            <SubMenu v-show="activeIndex === i"
                     v-if="visible(item)"
                     :items="item.items"
                     @menuitem-click="$emit('menuitem-click', $event)" />
          </template>
        </li>
        <li class="separator" />
      </template>
    </ul>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Options, Vue} from "vue-class-component";
import {PropType} from "vue";
import MenuItem from "@/classes/MenuItem";

@Options({
  name: 'SubMenu',
  props: {
    items: Array as PropType<MenuItem[]>,
    root: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
})
export default class SubMenu extends Vue {
  activeIndex: number = 0;

  visible(item: MenuItem): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
</script>
```

And the code for Menu:

```
<template>
  <div class="layout-menu-container">
    <SubMenu :items="model" :root="true" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Options, Vue} from "vue-class-component";
import {PropType} from "vue";
import SubMenu from "@/components/SubMenu.vue";
import MenuItem from "@/classes/MenuItem";

@Options({
  props: {
    model: {
      type: Array as PropType<MenuItem[]>
    }
  },
  components: {
    SubMenu
  }
})
export default class Menu extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

The particular error points to the `type: Boolean, default: false` line, and I've tried to use `type: PropType<Boolean>`, and set default to `Boolean(false)` too, but nothing seems to work. Even when I get rid of the root prop, it complains about the other props. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The error happens in a module that imports Menu.vue, this is not shown. "it complains about the other props" - how? The error that was posted doesn't mention props

Comment: @EstusFlask I have literally provided the Menu.vue code above. The error happens all the time for components that have props, however, I am able to circumvent the error by not using vue-class-component and just using `defineComponent`. It seems to be an issue with the way vue-class-component handles `props`, because I am able to use vue-class-component without props in other files just fine.

Comment: Again, the error occurs not in Menu.vue but in a module that uses it, this is what the error says. Please, clarify how that "without props" looked like. Was the whole `props` object missing, or `Options`, or? Any way, you can expect any kind of misconduct from vue-class-component, it works in obscure and undocumented way, doesn't specifically support Vue 3 and isn't maintained afaik.

Comment: The Vue class component syntax has been marked for deprecation for more than two years. Prominent Vue core members, including Evan You, have made it clear no efforts from core team will go into maintaining or supporting this syntax going forward, specifically because of the complex TypeScript problems the decorators created. That is the main reason for which this syntax was dropped. Perhaps you should address your question to the maintainers of the `vue-class-component` plugin, by opening an issue on their repo.

Comment: The only answer you'll get from the rest of the community is the one contained in the official documentation, use `defineComponent()`, which supports both Options API and Composition API out of the box.